# Substitute with an expression and matched pattern

Tags: vim

In vim we can substitute with an `sub-replace-expression`. When the substitute string starts with `\=` the remainder is interpreted as an expression.

e.g. with text:

```
bar
bar
```

and substitute command:

```
:%s/.*/\='foo \0'/
```

gives unexpected results:

```
foo \0
foo \0
```

instead of:

```
foo bar
foo bar
```

The question is: **How to evaluate expression with matched pattern in substitute?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use a *sub-replace-expression*, the normal special replacements like `&` and `\1` don't work anymore; everything is interpreted as a Vimscript expression. Fortunately, you can access the captured submatches with `submatches()`, so it becomes:

```
:%s/.*/\='foo ' . submatch(0)/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `:%s/.*/foo \0/`

With `:%s/.*/\='foo \0'/` you evaluate `'foo \0'` but that's a string and it evaluates to itself.

Comment: The question was how to evaluate matched pattern in expression not a normal find and replace.

Comment: Apparently the item in the second part of the substitution expression is automatically evaluated.

Comment: For me it's not evaluated automatically. I have Vim 7.3.1314.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to evaluate any expression for that, use a regex group and proper escapes

```
:%s /\(.*\)/foo \1/
```

Comment: Thanks. But actually I need to find out how to evaluate that is a main purpose of my question.